# Select not all columns when all checkboxes are unchecked when using Griddle

Tags: griddle

I use Griddle for displaying data, so I want to customize, what columns will be checked, when no columns are set, not all as by default.
For example:

```
<Griddle results={fakeData} tableClassName="table" showFilter={true}
 showSettings={true} columns={["name", "city", "state", "country"]}/>
```

I want to show name and city, when all checkboxes are unchecked. How can I do this? In official documentation I found only

> If no columns are set, Griddle will display all columns by default.

Comment: Please post your relevant codes, analysis done on the issue as well. As this seems a very low quality post otherwise.